# Why can't I get the value from formula in module2 into module1?

Tags: excel, vba

I have three modules in my excel VBA. My main calculation is written in module1 and i want to call subs from module2 like this (simplified):

module1:

```
sub sub_a()

  'some syntaks here

  call sub_b()

sheet1.cells(1,1)=a

end sub
```

module2:

```
sub sub_b()

   a=5

end sub
```

And the problem is: why in `sheet1.cells(1,1)` the value a doesn't come out? What's wrong?

Comment: are your `a` variable is global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you need to define "a" as a global variable.  It will then be visible to other subroutines.
E.G.:

module1:

```
sub sub_a()

  'some syntaks here

  call sub_b()

sheet1.cells(1,1)=a

end sub
```

module2:

```
Global a as integer
sub sub_b()

   a=5

end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can't reference the value set in the sub_b because it is private to that sub.

Besides using Global, another way to return a single value to a caller is to use a user-defined function like this:

```
Sub sub_a()
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = Fun_b 'the right-hand side is a function call to fun_b
End Sub

Function Fun_b() as Variant 'Specify the appropriate type to your needs
   a = 5
   Fun_b = a 'assign the result of execution here and return
End Function
```

It is recommended that you build code using functions instead of sharing variables across subs arbitrary because if you have a large application, it will be difficult to track where variables are being changed.

Functions also allow you to pass parameters.

Learn more about user-defined functions [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx).